# Can only pull/call React Native state on the second iteration after updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state

I have a Formik form that updates the state. However, I can only use the state when I hit "submit" again.

```
 onSubmit={(values) => {
          addData(values);
          console.log(data);
        }}>
```

```
  const addData = (billing) => {
    setData((currentData) => {
      const shipping = {
        first_name: billing.first_name,
        last_name: billing.last_name,
        address_1: billing.address_1,
        address_2: billing.address_2,
        city: billing.city,
        state: billing.state,
        postcode: billing.postcode,
        country: billing.country,
      };
      const line_items = items;
      return {billing, shipping, line_items, ...currentData};
    });
    console.log(data);
  };
```

I know that the values update because before I click a second time, if I comment out the "addData" function I can still see my data logged. However, On the first time I hit "submit" the values do not log. I need to be able to call the values in the same function so I can make an API call and push them to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming setData is coming from the useState hook, its an asynchronous function, so it wont update the values immediately.

One way to solve the issue is to use the useEffect hook and listen for changes of data variable but here it wont work as you need it inside the other function.

You can solve it by changing the flow like below.

```
 const addData = (billing) => {
  const shipping = {
    first_name: billing.first_name,
    last_name: billing.last_name,
    address_1: billing.address_1,
    address_2: billing.address_2,
    city: billing.city,
    state: billing.state,
    postcode: billing.postcode,
    country: billing.country,
  };
  const line_items = items;
  const updatedData = { billing, shipping, line_items, ...data };

  setData(updatedData);
  console.log(updatedData);

  return updatedData;
};
```

This will update the state and also return the value which you can use immediately in the submit function.

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
  const updateData=   addData(values);
  console.log(updateData);
}}>
```

Comment: is there a way to use an async function to wait for the data to be updated and then do the next step? I'm asking because I need to run setData and add tax to the state. To do this I made a separate function. How can I call another function after addData(values) to setData

Comment: Then you will have to use the 'useEffect' hook and check for value change